# Open link in same page different section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, href

I have two different html files in my application. 
Something like this.

```
<a href="/conversations/<%= c['conversation']['id'] %>" class="list-group-item">
  <div id="nav">
   <p>This is link my second page</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

This is my second page.

```
div id="nav">
  <p>This is link my second page</p>
</div>
```

But here when I click on link it is redirect to second page. What I want is when I click on the link I want to open the second html, within the different section of the same page.
Some thing like this.
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can open a new page within the same page in a different section.Either you can open a complete new page with a new link in same page by setting (<a target="_self">) target property to self. Otherwise you will have to use an iframe which itself is embeded html within a page to open a new html within a section of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe is the tag which you can use for call other html pages into your web page

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.co.in" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <div>
      <a class"links" href="https://www.yourlink.com/">link1</a>
      <a class"links" href="https://www.yourlink2.com/">link2</a>
    </div>

<div id="target_div">
  content here
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".links").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(url);
    $("#target_div").html('<iframe src="' + url + '" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');
  });
});
```

try this